# How to add Dialog component into BottomNavigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add Dialog component into BottomNavigation so that when user click on the search icon in bottomNavigation it will trigger a simple dialog box, but it is now showing this error as shown below:

[image: component prop invalid]

Below is my current code.

Menu.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import SearchDialog from './SearchDialog'

// material ui imports 
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import BottomNavigation from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation'
import BottomNavigationAction from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigationAction'
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge'
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home'
import CartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCart'
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        position: "fixed",
        width: '100vw', 
        bottom: 0,
        zIndex: 2,
    },
    actionItemStyles: {
        "&$selected": {
            color: '#827153'
        }
    },
    selected : {}
});

// create a ref to Dialog component
const SearchDialogContent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => 
    <SearchDialog {...props} ref={ref}>{props.children}</SearchDialog >)

const Menu = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <BottomNavigation 
            value={value} 
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {setValue(newValue)}}
            className={classes.root}
        >
            <BottomNavigationAction label="Store" icon={<HomeIcon/>} component={Link} to={'/'}/>
            <BottomNavigationAction label="Cart" 
                icon={<Badge max={99} badgeContent={0} color="secondary"><CartIcon/></Badge>} 
                component={Link} to={'/cart'}/>
            <BottomNavigationAction label="Search" icon={<SearchIcon/>} onClick={handleClickOpen}
                component={SearchDialogContent} open={open} handleClose={handleClose}/>
        </BottomNavigation>
    );
}

export default React.memo(Menu);
```

SearchDialog.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog'
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions'
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent'
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText'
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle'
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide'

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction = "up" ref = {ref} {...props}/>;})

const SearchDialog = (props) => {
    const {open, handleClose} = props;

    console.log(open) // props is passed correctly 
                
    return ( 
        <Dialog 
            open = {open}
            TransitionComponent = {Transition}
            keepMounted 
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
        > 
            <DialogTitle>Title</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
               <DialogContentText>
                   Dialog content description here
               </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogAction>
                <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">Close</Button>
            </DialogAction>
        </Dialog>
}
export default SearchDialog;
```

The props can be passed correctly, but it was not able to render it for some reason. What am I doing wrong ?

Added a [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-dream-omxjf)

Comment: if you want to forward your ref to another component then use `forwardRef` instead of `useRef`

Comment: Hi, it is already ```forwardRef``` isn't it ?